Why is my type-parameter in this impl block unconstrained?
Hopefully a straightforward question for the Rust generics wizards. I'm looking to write a Display impl for anything that can be borrowed as my Offset type (e.g. Offset, &Offset, Box<Offset>, etc). And have come up with the following:
impl<O, C> Display for Modification<O>
where
    O: Borrow<Offset<C>>,
    C: Display,

What I believe is causing the issue here is that my Offset struct has a type-parameter, and that parameter needs to implement Display for the overall Modification<O> to do so.
As is, this code generates the error:
error[E0207]: the type parameter `C` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> crates/polychem/src/polymers/modification.rs:42:9
   |
42 | impl<O, C> Display for Modification<O>
   |         ^ unconstrained type parameter

From my perspective, it is very much indeed constrained by the impl predicates, and this works just fine:
impl<O, C> Display for Modification<O>
where
    O: Borrow<C>,
    C: Display,

So something about throwing that generic struct in the mix is either (1) revealing a limitation in Rust's trait-solving, or — much more likely — (2) is indeed unconstrained nonsense, but in a way I don't currently I understand...
Happy to provide more information and context if it's deemed helpful!

It is unconstrained.
Rust requires that a given trait be implemented for a type at most once. (This is called coherence.)  However, this impl block allows for an infinite number of implementations of Display for one instantiation of Modification<O> by varying the C type.
Because Borrow is generic, it's possible for the concrete type represented by O to implement Borrow<Offset<A>> and Borrow<Offset<B>> for different types A and B.  Which one should the impl block choose?  There's no clear way to decide, and therefore this impl is disallowed.

From my perspective, it is very much indeed constrained by the impl predicates, and this works just fine

No, this also fails:
error[E0207]: the type parameter `C` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/lib.rs:6:9
  |
6 | impl<O, C> Display for Modification<O>
  |         ^ unconstrained type parameter

One way you could solve this is by creating a trait that uses an associated type instead of a generic to specify the "canonical" offset type:
trait BorrowOffset: Borrow<Offset<Self::OffsetType>> {
    type OffsetType;
}

Now you can reference this associated type in the Display implementation for Modification<O> instead of needing an impl generic type:
impl<O> Display for Modification<O>
where
    O: BorrowOffset,
    O::OffsetType: Display,
{
    // ...
}


Thanks for the quick answer! I can understand how this breaks Rust's coherence rules, though I'm not sure I fully grasp the "which one should the impl block choose" rationale, since every possible impl be the same? Though I suppose you could end up with differences after monomorphization?
As an aside, it seems odd the Borrow trait in std doesn't use an associated type... The AsRef documentation makes clear that, Borrow shouldn't really be used to return any fields, since the owned and borrowed representations should be Eq.
Regardless, thanks for the quick sanity check!

Essentially, it would be nice to have a trait like Deref in the std that has the blanket impl from Borrow: impl<T> Deref<Target = T> for T

I'm not sure I understand what Deref has to do with this. "though I'm not sure I fully grasp the "which one should the impl block choose" rationale, since every possible impl be the same" -- They would have the same code, but different meaning. If O implements Borrow<Offset<A>> and Borrow<Offset<B>> then the implementation could use either A's Display implementation or B's. Can you tell me which one it should choose and why?

I can see the issue with the trait impls being ambiguous there! I've also realized part of the reason I was confused was because these things seemed to work for generic functions, but of course that's because they don't need to adhere to these cohearance rules, since you can disambiguate using the turbofish. The particular issue with borrow, I think, is that semantically, I don't think you ever should have both of those options (since Eq, etc should be the same for the owned version). I think (from what I can tell) Borrow would make more sense to have an associated type like Deref!

@Brooks It is conceivable that you could offer two different borrows that compare as equal the same way the base value does, so I don't think there is a conflict there. Consider PathBuf which implements Borrow<Path> -- conceptually, it could also implement Borrow<str> if not for the fact that PathBuf can represent invalid UTF-8 sequences and &str cannot. I do agree it would be simpler with an associated type, but I think there are cases where it can make sense to implement it for different types.

@Brooks Regardless, you've hit the nail on the head in terms of your understanding of the issue. Using your own trait with an associated type (as proposed in my answer) is probably the quickest way to fix your issue, though there are other approaches that could work as well.
